# Is the global solution to this ODE bounded?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Consider
$$\dot{\theta_i}=-\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j),\ i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$$
where $A_{ij}$ is adjacency matrix of a connected simple graph, and the vector $\theta=[\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n]\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is: is the global solution to this ODE bounded? I.e. for any initial condition $\theta(0)\in\,\mathbb{R}^n$, can we or when can we conclude that there exists a nonnegative $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|\theta(t)\|\leq M$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is certain norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as long as the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in $\Bbb R^n$ is correct in this  norm sense)?

Additional information:

We can represent the $\theta_i$ as angle on a unit circle, and simulate the ode to see how these $n$ angles move on the circle. If the solution is unbounded, then in the simulation we should see there exists an angle moves in one direction forever, and never stop.
According to numerical experiments, I never observe this type of phenemenon. I conjecture that the solution is indeed bounded, or at least, the set of unbounded solutions is very 'thin', maybe in the sense of measure zero.

Comment: I think you don't have to say that the graph is connected, because you can deal with this component-wise.

Comment: I think we can generalize to rationally weighted graphs by replacing each vertex with a cluster of vertices.  This gives more ways to construct an unbounded example.

Comment: I’d conjecture that unbounded examples exist: heuristically, if you start with very large $\theta$, the derivatives between the various nodes are close to unrelated.  It seems likely you can pick a configuration that ratchets up to a higher equivalent period, which would then walk up to infinity.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving how to understand 'the derivatives of $\theta_i$ are unrelated'? many thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the sum of the $\theta_i$ is constant (it has zero derivative) so if the norm unbounded then we need some values going to negative infinity, others to positive infinity.

Comment: More generally, one can ask if the trajectory of the gradient flow with periodic real-analytic potential can escape to infinity. This is *extremely* unlikely for many reasons (for instance, if the critical points are isolated, it is trivially impossible) but I can come up with neither a proof or an example yet.